# Microsoft Excel GUI missing text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Please refer to the picture of what the situation is: [image: Graphical User Interface (GUI) missing text].

Basically what happens is in the picture. When I leave excel open too long, or when I have to switch windows and return to excel, I get the bug. Can't search it on the web bc I can't quite explain this. Not to mention it sucks because I have to restart excel every time this happens.

---

This is MS Excel 2016 PP, 64bit. My machine runs on 8GB RAM, i5-5005U 2.3 GHz. I want to have MS repair the application, but I don't really have the time to go through that.

Comment: What screen are we even looking at?  There really isn't enough information here for people to even guess at what's going on.

Comment: @fixer1234 it's the "File" screen on Excel 2016.

Comment: Could do with addtional information, like is this a new install? is this the 32-bit or 64-bit version? when did this issue first start occurring? what is your computer specifications(eg. cpu/ram)? The more detailed information you can provide in your question the better the answers will be.

Comment: @angelofdev I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is that your system is running low on memory, sadly not enough information is out there currently regarding this issue.

However as per the suggestion on [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-2016-missingblank-ui/7ae1a9e4-5370-4610-8c9a-6d89b15a5605)

You could try the following steps:

**Option 1**. Repair the Office applications.

**Option 2**. Reinstall a 32-bit Office suite.

1. Remove the Office applications with the Fix it tool.
2. Restart your computer.
3. Reinstall the 32-bit Office suite.